# NoMethodFoundException - Jackson yaml parser & snakeYAML

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, snakeyaml

i'm getting the following exception when trying to convert a yaml string to a class

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.<init>(org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader, org.yaml.snakeyaml.LoaderOptions)'
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLParser.<init>(YAMLParser.java:204)
```

When performing this code:

```
try {
     MyClass claseIns = mapper.readValue(string, MyClass.class);
         MyClass.add(claseIns);
         } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Spring boot version 2.7.13

build.gradle includes:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:2.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.15.2'
}
```

From searching online it seems like a version problem between jackson and snakeYAML, but as you can see here it says jackson 2.15.2 is compatible with snakeYAML 2.0: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml/2.15.2